# Can the Measureit Addon measure an animated armature?

Tags: armature, measurement

https://ephmedia.giphy.com/dbe8121d-4453-4ae0-9569-97093c12948b.gif

I am using the Measureit Addon to measure the angle of these 3 vertices. When I parent or hook one of the vertices to an empty and animate the empty, the angle no longer displays.

Measureit only seems to work with vertices, not empties or bones. I can use animALL Addon to manually keyframe a vertice (second gif), but I want an automatic setup.

https://ephmedia.giphy.com/28d1e277-ee90-4b8f-b48d-8b0197196b30.gif